# Automatic messages are not occurring

Tags: support, bug

Yesterday,

When viewing a question/answer:

1. the vote counts updated automatically.
2. a banner automatically told when a post was added or updated.

When viewing the Questions page:

1. a banner automatically told when a question was added or updated.

However, none of these happen today. The only difference from yesterday is that I shut down my computer and started it back up after a 5 hour drive.

Is there some way to control these actions? Is anyone else not seeing these automatic messages/actions?

OS and browser info: Mac OS 10.5.8, Firefox 11.0

**Additional Information**

It appears this may have something to do with my IP address. I am away from home and connect by tethering through my iPhone.  When connecting without VPN, the automatic updating stops. However, if I connect to the VPN server back home, everything updates automatically, eventhough I am still tethered through my iPhone.

Comment: Try driving back the way in the reverse, maybe it will undo the problem. :-)

Comment: @DylanMoreland: good idea! (shame on me)

Comment: The browser feature you need for this to work is [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), there are a few sites where you can test if your setup supports WebSocket linked on that Wikipedia page.